# Load credentials in python package

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, credentials

I'm developing a Python package to communicate with an API. In order not to hard code the username and password I would like to read the credentials from a JSON file loacated in a 'conf' directory. So if no username and pasword are given it tries to load the credentials from the file:

```
def __init__(self, user=None, pswd=None):
        """ Illustrate method-level docstring."""
        if pswd is None:
            try:
                with open('conf/credentials.json') as data_file:
                    data = json.load(data_file)
                    user = data['user']
                    pswd = data['password']
                    print('You will log in with user', user)
            except IOError:
                print("Could not read file: credentials.json. Please Instantiate object with your username and password")
```

This solution works fine when executing the code in the same directory, but once the package is installed the system doesn't find the file:

```
Could not read file: credentials.json. Please Instantiate object with
your username and password
```

How can I overcome this problem? Is it possible to refer to the installation path? I don't want to encrypt the password, I just want to have the credentials in a separate file and add the file in the *.gitignore* file to prevent sharing this information.

Comment: You can use something like Configparser

Comment: Try providing the full path to the json

Answer (score 0):

You may try using '**file**' which stores filename (with absolute or relative path) and build your path based on this.

You may also store your secret data in other directory (outside of your codebase) like ~/. It may be even better to pass this filename as environmental variable (see os.environ) so users may point to the right file.